# Can I return a double or float in a function with two integer parameters?

Tags: c, void

I would like compute the average of numbers with a function in this program, but it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i;
int size = 6;

int main () {
    int arr[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    avg (arr, & size);

    return 0;
}

double avg (int a[], int *n ) {
    int sum = 0;
    double average;

    for (i = 0 ; i < *n ; i++) {
        sum  = sum + a[i];
    }
    average = (double) sum / *n;
    return average;
}
```

But if I do it with the same simple void function instead, it works correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i;
int size = 6;

int main () {
    int arr[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    avg(arr, & size);

    return 0;
}

void avg (int a[], int *n) {
    int sum = 0;
    double average;

    for (i = 0 ; i < *n ; i++) {
        sum  = sum + a[i];
    }

    average = (double) sum / *n;
    printf("%lf", average);
}
```

What is the difference between these two void functions and a simple function?

Comment: What is a `simple void function`?

Comment: 1) you should declare `double avg  (int a[] , int *n );` before the main and 2) you're not printing the returned result. it won't print itself...

Comment: The first snippet missing a print statement.

Comment: Why are you passing a pointer to the size instead of just the size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you haven't declared your function before using it in `main()`. Provide a declaration or prototype before calling it.

```
double avg(int a[], int *n);
int main() { 
...
```

Second, in the first implementation, you are not storing the return value of the function

```
avg (arr, & size) ; // useless statement
```

Just store the return value into a variable and print it, it will work as expected

```
double average = avg (arr, & size);
printf("%lf", average);
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I didn't know that I have to declare a prototype for function. I mostly used void functions, and them worked without prototype declaration too.

Comment: @jaraipali declaration is required for all type of functions you are using in your program, unless you are defining them before calling.